# Automate Azure Data Factory triggers using release pipeline by using powershell task

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management, azure-data-factory

I am new on DevOps, i am trying to change Azure Data Factory triggers starttime and endtime properties in azure data factory at deployment time using powershell.

I found this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/set-azdatafactoryv2trigger?view=azps-2.6.0) and tried to follow in PowerShell. I am getting following error when i am running below command.

```
PS C:\> Set-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "WikiADF" -Name "ScheduledTrigger" -DefinitionFile ".\scheduledTrigger.json"

Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 : The term 'Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:16
+ $DataFactory = Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $ResGrp.Re ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I searched about this issue and found this issue as a bug in [Microsoft official github account](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/30971)

If anyone able to resolved this issue or have already resolved, please help me.

***Note: Azure DataFactory Triggers tag is not available in StackOverflow, so i am not able to add it.***

Comment: Any time youe see _The term 'xyz' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet_ in powershell, it means you haven't installed the module. At the top of the page it tells you which module you need to install. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/set-azurermdatafactoryv2?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very agreed with Nick's opinion:

> Any time youe see The term 'xyz' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet in powershell, it means you haven't installed the module.

Actually, in your issue, the error also caused by this reason. I think you should haven't installed the `Az` module for your Powershell.

The `Az` module is a rollup module for the Azure PowerShell cmdlets. Installing it can download all of the available Azure Resource Manager modules, include the `Set-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger` you are using, and makes their cmdlets available for use.

Try this command to install the `Az` module for your Powershell:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
```

[image]

Since as default, the `PowerShell` gallery isn't configured as a trusted repository for `PowerShellGet`, the first time you use the `PSGallery` you would see the prompt which need you ensure if you want to get the `Az` module from PSGallery. Just answer Yes or Yes to All is ok.

Then, you can execute the following command to check the Az module:

```
 Get-InstalledModule -Name Az
```

When you see the following message, it means the `Az` module has exists in the Powershell:

[image]

Now, try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/set-azdatafactoryv2trigger?view=azps-2.6.0) again, it would be succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to use PowerShell task instead of Azure PowerShell task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) in your release pipeline.

You won't have any issue if using Azure PowerShell task.